# Haskell random numbers

Tags: haskell

I am trying to generate a sample of random numbers in Haskell

```
import System.Random

getSample n = take n $ randoms g where
    g = newStdGen
```

but it seems I am not quite using `newStdGen` the right way. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you probably don't want to use `newStdGen`. The biggest problem is that you'll get a different seed every time you run your program, so no results will be reproducible. In my opinion, `mkStdGen` is a better choice as it requires you to give it a seed.  This means you will get the same sequence of (pseudo)random numbers every time. If you want a different sequence, just change the seed.

The second problem with `newStdGen` is that since it's impure, you'll end up in the IO monad which can be a bit inconvenient.

```
sample :: Int -> IO [Int]
sample n = do
  gen <- newStdGen
  return $ take n $ randoms gen
```

You can use do-notation to 'extract' the values and then sum them:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  xs <- sample 10
  s = sum xs
  print s
```

Or you could 'fmap' the function over the result (but notice that at some point you will probably need to extract the value):

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  s <- fmap sum $ sample 10
  print s
```

The `fmap` function is a generalized version of `map`. Just like `map` applies a function to the values inside a list, `fmap` can apply a function to values inside `IO`.

Another problem with this `sample` function is that if we call it again, it starts with a fresh seed instead of continuing the previous (pseudo)random sequence. Again, this make reproducing results impossible. In order to fix this problem, we need to pass in the seed and return a new seed. Unfortunately, `randoms` does not return the next seed for us, so we'll have to write this from scratch using `random`.

```
sample :: Int -> StdGen -> ([Int],StdGen)
sample n seed1 = case n of
  0 -> ([],seed1)
  k -> let (rs,seed2) = sample (k-1) seed1
           (r, seed3) = random seed2
        in ((r:rs),seed3)
```

Our main function is now

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  let seed1 = mkStdGen 123456
      (xs,seed2) = sample 10 seed1
      s = sum xs
      (ys,seed3) = sample 10 seed2
      t = sum ys
  print s
  print t
```

I know this seems like an awful lot of work just to to use random numbers, but the advantages are worth it. We can generate all of our randomness with a single seed which guarantees that the results can be reproduced.

Of course, this being Haskell, we can take advantage of Monads to get rid of all the manual threading of the seed values. This is a slightly more advanced method, but well worth learning since monads are ubiquitous in Haskell code.

We need these imports:

```
import System.Random
import Control.Monad
import Control.Applicative
```

Then we'll create a newtype which represents the action of turning a seed into a value and the next seed.

```
newtype Rand a = Rand { runRand :: StdGen -> (a,StdGen) }
```

We need `Functor` and `Applicative` instances or GHC will complain, but we can avoid implementing them for this example.

```
instance Functor Rand
instance Applicative Rand
```

And now for the Monad instance. This is where the magic happens. The `>>=` function (called bind) is the one place where we specify how to thread the seed value through the computation.

```
instance Monad Rand where
  return x = Rand ( \seed -> (x,seed) )
  ra >>= f = Rand ( \s1 -> let (a,s2) = runRand ra s1
                           in  runRand (f a) s2 )

newRand :: Rand Int
newRand = Rand ( \seed -> random seed )
```

Now our `sample` function is extremely simple! We can take advantage of `replicateM` from `Control.Monad` which repeats a given action and accumulates the results in a list. All that funny business with the seed values is taken care of behind the scenes

```
sample :: Int -> Rand [Int]
sample n = replicateM n newRand

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let seed1 = mkStdGen 124567
      (xs,seed2) = runRand (sample 10) seed1
      s = sum xs
  print s
```

We can even stay inside the `Rand` monad if we need to generate random values multiple times.

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  let seed1 = mkStdGen 124567
      (xs,seed2) = flip runRand seed1 $ do
        x <- newRand
        bs <- sample 5
        cs <- sample 10
        return $ x : (bs ++ cs)
      s = sum xs
  print s
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! Here's a thing that's confusing me: I started with a pure function that needs a list of random numbers as input (essentially doing a `sum $ map someFunction randomNumbers`). However, the random numbers generated above are monadic (is that a word?) and it seems that I can't just stick them inside my pure function. What is the proper way to resolve this in Haskell?

Comment: I don't think there is one "proper" way to do it. I've outlined my personal preference above. You are probably more interested in the "most expedient" way to solve your immediate problem. In that case try either `fmap sum $ map someFunction randomNumbers`, or use `mkStdGen 123456` insteand of `newStdGen`. (123456 can be any arbitrary integer)